# Can we use create and use custom EventHandler classes in JAVAFX?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have a question on the Event Handling in JavaFX. As per the tutorial (and other examples that I came across), event handling is carried the following way in JavaFX:

```
Button addBtn = new Button("Add");
addBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Add Clicked");
    }
});
```

But, I am wondering, if I can "handle" the button click the following way:

```
Button addBtn = new Button("Add");
addBtn.setOnAction(new addButtonClicked());
```

where `addButtonClicked()` is my own Class (with it's own set of methods and functionality) that I have defined and written to handle the actions for the button click.

Is there a way to attach my own event handler classes for buttons in JavaFX?

Comment: possible duplicate of [registering mouse handler but handler not inline, in javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326180/registering-mouse-handler-but-handler-not-inline-in-javafx)

Answer (score 6):

The EventHandler is an interface class.
So, it should be "implements" not "extends"

```
private static class AddButtonClicked implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          System.out.println("My Very Own Private Button Handler");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
private static class AddButtonClicked extends EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          System.out.println("My Very Own Private Button Handler");
     }
}
```

Comment: Can't wait for lambdas in Java 8